# Neural Network for Regression with tflearn

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, regression, tflearn

My question is about coding a neural network which does regression (and NOT classification) using tflearn.

Dataset:

```
fixed acidity  volatile acidity  citric acid  ...  alcohol  quality   
7.4             0.700            0.00         ...  9.4        5    
7.8             0.880            0.00         ...  9.8        5  
7.8             0.760            0.04         ...  9.8        5     
11.2            0.280            0.56         ...  9.8        6      
7.4             0.700            0.00         ...  9.4        5
```

I want to build a neural network which takes in 11 features (chemical values in wine) and outputs or predicts a score i.e., quality(out of 10). I DON'T want to classify the wine like quality_1, quality_2,... I want the model to perform a regression function for my features and predict a value out of 10(could be even a float).

The quality column in my data only has values = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
It does not contain 1, 2, and 10.

Due to the lack in experience, I could only code a neural network that CLASSIFIES the wine into classes like [score_3, score_4,...] and I used one hot encoding to do so.

Processed Data:

Features:

```
[[  7.5999999    0.23         0.25999999 ...,   3.02999997   0.44
    9.19999981]
 [  6.9000001    0.23         0.34999999 ...,   2.79999995   0.54000002
   11.        ]
 [  6.69999981   0.17         0.37       ...,   3.25999999   0.60000002
   10.80000019]
 ..., 
 [  6.30000019   0.28         0.47       ...,   3.11999989   0.50999999
    9.5       ]
 [  5.19999981   0.64499998   0.         ...,   3.77999997   0.61000001
   12.5       ]
 [  8.           0.23999999   0.47999999 ...,   3.23000002   0.69999999
   10.        ]]
```

Labels:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Code for a neural network which CLASSIFIES into different classes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


def preprocess():

    data_source_red = 'F:\Gautam\...\Datasets\winequality-red.csv'
  
    data_red = pd.read_csv(data_source_red, index_col=False, sep=';')
            
    data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['quality'], prefix=['score'])

    x = data[data.columns[0:11]].values
    y = data[data.columns[11:18]].values

    x = np.float32(x)
    y = np.float32(y)

    return (x, y)


x, y = preprocess()

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2)

network = input_data(shape=[None, 11], name='Input_layer')

network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='relu', name='Hidden_layer_1')

network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='relu', name='Hidden_layer_2')

network = fully_connected(network, 7, activation='softmax', name='Output_layer')

network = regression(network, batch_size=2, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01)

model = tflearn.DNN(network)

model.fit(train_x, train_y, show_metric=True, run_id='wine_regression',
          validation_set=0.1, n_epoch=1000)
```

The neural network above is a poor one(accuracy=0.40). Moreover, it classifies the data into different classes. I would like to know how to code a regression neural network which gives a score out of 10 for the input features (and NOT CLASSIFICATION). I would also prefer tflearn as I'm quite comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line in your code which makes your network a classifier with seven categories, instead of a regressor:

```
network = fully_connected(network, 7, activation='softmax', name='Output_layer')
```

I don't use TFLearn any more, I have switched over to Keras (which is similar, and has better support).  However, I will suggest that you want the following output layer instead:

```
network = fully_connected(network, 1, activation='linear', name='Output_layer')
```

Also, your training data will need to change.  If you want to perform a regression, you want a one-dimensional scalar label instead.  I assume that you still have the original data, which you say that you altered?  If not, [the UC Irvine Machine Learning Data Repository has the wine quality data with a single, numerical Quality column](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality).

Comment: I removed `pd.get_dummies` which makes OneHotCoding. So, now I have the dataset as it was. I changed `y = data[data.columns[11:18]].values` to `y = data[data.columns[11]].values` so now I have my label data as : `[ 5.  5.  5. ...,  6.  5.  6.]` I changed the output layer to what you had suggested. But now I get a value error. Error: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'`

Comment: I think that the `shape (2,)` problem has to do with the fact that you chose a batch size of 2.  You can confirm that by trying a different batch size.  I also think that the way to solve it is to wrap your single output column in an extra dimension.  After you create y in `preprocess()`, try `y = np.expand_dims(y,-1)`.  (This is the kind of thing that I find that Keras handles more automatically.)

Comment: Yes, `shape(2, )` was because my batch size is 2. I checked it by changing the batch size. After applying this code: `y = np.expand_dims(, -1)` my model works fine. I even predicted the score out of 10. Thanks a lot. One more issue, while running the code I got `loss = 0.00` and `binary_accuracy = 0.00` But while evaluating my model using `print(model.evaluate(test_x, test_y))` I got output as [0.93...] Does that mean my model got 93% accuracy in the test data?

Comment: I changed this line: `network = regression(network, batch_size=2, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01)` to `network = regression(network, batch_size=1, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01, loss='mean_square', metric='R2')` Now while training the model, I get loss and R2 values. What is R2 and what should be its ideal value?? Sometimes, R2 shoots more than 1.0 like 1.023. What is R2 and how does it differ from accuracy? Thanks again!